# IndexedDB - Counting value occurrences?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I'm working on a chrome extension for an online Japanese dictionary and I'm trying to record and display querying statistics of the user so he knows what Japanese terms he is missing the most.

For that my intention was to show the most queried *kanji*(Japanese characters) in the last X days. So I made a simple object store in my extension indexedDB with kanji/date pairs and autonumered keys but there doesn't seem to be a way to do these queries in indexedDB?

Is the only way to filter by date and count the occurrences using a cursor and doing it with the javascript callback?

EDIT: code used to create the database

```
const DB_NAME = "kioku"
const DB_VERSION = 1;
const KANJI_STORE = "kanji";

var db;
(function() {
    var request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        db = e.target.result;
        var kanjiStore = db.createObjectStore(KANJI_STORE, { autoIncrement: true });
        kanjiStore.createIndex("date", "date", { unique: false });
    }
})();
```

Adding data through an event handler

```
function newRecentKanjiHandler(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    /* ...stuff before this point was irrelevant so I removed it */

    var kanjiStore = db.transaction([KANJI_STORE], "readwrite").objectStore(KANJI_STORE);
    kanjiStore.add({kanji: request.kanji, date: Date.now()});
}
```

An screenshot with sample data

[image: Screenshot with sample data]

In this case I would like to display something like

```
x3: 杉
x2: 刀, 尻
x1: 刃
```

For the user. Just a simple counting of occurrences after I filter by a date range, which I haven't in this example because the timestamps are within an hour and my intent is to filter the last few days or weeks.

Comment: I'll give you a full response tonight, but totally possible. In the meantime, can you post your schema and some example data? A screenshot of Chrome resources panel would likely suffice.

Comment: @buley I can't post a screenshot because AFAIK the only way to access that is opening the developer tools in the extension background page, and there seems to be [a bug that makes Chrome crash every time I try to open that page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340235). But I'll post more details about the schema.

Comment: @buley nevermind my last comment. I was able to take an screenshot by opening the developer tools in my extension's options page instead of the background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this question. I am positive someone will have a better answer than me but here is a random go at it.

First, I should point out an aside, that you are going to run into problems with trying to assign event.target.result to db. You are trying to shove an object that is only valid within its scope into an outer scope. This is just going to cause you problems later. I suggest learning more about asynchronous functions in JavaScript.

Second, I would start by taking a step back from the current direction and review some basic assumptions about the problem you are trying to solve. Sometimes indexedDB is not the best solution. Unfortunately, using indexedDB forces you to confront these design questions sooner rather than later.

Do you need to store every key event? If not, then the scale of the problem is limited to the number of different kanji keys and not the number of events. You could forego using indexedDB altogether and use a simple object that you persist to local storage.

If the scale is kind of large, then determine whether you are storing the events for just the purpose of your question, or for other purposes? If it is only the purpose of your own question, then consider changing what you are storing (the schema) to only address its particular purpose, and not an unknown list of other purposes.

For example, if it is just for this purpose, and it does not have to scale, you can avoid indexedDB entirely and just local storage. Something like the following:

```
function onCharEvent(char) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.KANJI_STATS || '');
  var bar = obj[char] || {char: char, count: 0};
  bar.count++;
  bar.lastObserved = Date.now();
  obj[char] = bar;
  localStorage.KANJI_STATS = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

If the feature is just for this purpose, and it has to be large scale, you can simplify the schema. Begin by imagining what the list-like result of the query should look like after all grouping and ordering and counting is done. Then think about how you would go about performing add and put operations into this schema. If I understand you correctly, you want to obtain a collection of results that looks like the following:

```
Kanji char | Count | Last observed
----------------------------------
char1      | 1     | 1234123412345
char2      | 2     | 4643563456345
char3      | 3     | 3245234523452
```

Every instance (record) contains a unique character. The count represents the number of times the character was observed. The last-observed property represents the time the character was most recently observed.

```
// Setup or change the schema
function onUpgradeNeeded() {
  var db = this.result;
  var store = db.createObjectStore('kanji', {keyPath: kanjiChar});
  store.createIndex('lastObserved','lastObserved');
}

function openDB(onOpen) {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(DBNAME,DBVERSION);
  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = onUpgradeNeeded;
  openrequest.onsuccess = function() {
    onOpen(this.result);
  };
}

function onKeyEvent(event) {
  var kanjiChar = event.target.value;
  openDB(function(db) {
    put(db, kanjiChar);
  });
}

// Insert or update the kanji in the store
function put(db, kanjiChar, oncomplete) {
  var tx = db.transaction('kanji','readwrite');
  tx.oncomplete = function() {
    oncomplete(kanjiChar);
  };

  var store = tx.objectStore('kanji');      
  store.openCursor(kanji).onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = this.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var obj = cursor.value;
      obj.count = obj.count ? obj.count + 1 : 1;
      obj.lastObserved = Date.now();
      cursor.update(obj);
    } else {
      store.add({
        kanjiChar: kanji,
        count: 1,
        lastObserved: Date.now()
      });
    }
  };
}

function getStats(db, oncomplete) {
  var tx = db.transaction('kanji');
  var allStats = [];

  tx.oncomplete = function() {
    oncomplete(allStats);
  };

  var kanjiStore = tx.objectStore('kanji');
  var lastObservedIndex = kanjiStore.index('lastObserved');
  var LIMIT = 10;
  var counter = 0;
  lastObservedIndex.openCursor('prev').onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = this.result;
    if(cursor) {
      allStats.push(cursor.value);
      if(counter++ < LIMIT) {
        // Only continue 
        cursor.continue();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Indeed recording each event may not be necessary, however I wanted to preserve all the data from the events so I could analyze them after a trial period and decide what works best and what could be tossed away. That said, your answer made me realize that, for the purpose I intend to use this, that is, for users to be informed what kanji they end up querying most for, and furthermore which kanji they should focus their studies on, the solution you proposed should work well enough. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting it, but please understand, I didn't mean to discourage you from your quest. Preserving for a period of time to think more about it is a valid 'alternative reason' that suggests indexedDB would be a great solution. In that sense, can you describe very clearly what the result of the GROUP BY operation would look like? Like, what would it be if you were doing it in good old SQL?

Comment: I don't actually know SQL but I think it should be like this `SELECT kanji, COUNT(*) as occurences FROM kanji WHERE date > <some value> GROUP BY kanji ORDER BY occurences DESC`. [Crude SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec61e/9/0)